# string.matches(regex) returns false, although I think it should be true

Tags: java, regex, match

I am working with Java regular expressions.

Oh, I really miss Perl!! Java regular expressions are so hard.

Anyway, below is my code.

```
oneLine = "{\"kind\":\"list\",\"items\"";
System.out.println(oneLine.matches("kind"));
```

I expected "true" to be shown on the screen, but I could only see "false".

What's wrong with the code? And how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Try the other way around: "kind".matches(oneLine);

Comment: For this example at least, you could just use `contains`.

Answer (score 8):

[`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regex as parameter, in which anchors are implicit. So, your regex pattern will be matched at the beginning till the end of the string.

Since your string does not start with `"kind"`, so it returns `false`.

Now, as per your current problem, I think you don't need to use `regex` here. Simply using [`String#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method will work fine: -

```
oneLine.contains("kind");
```

Or, if you want to use `matches`, then build the regex to match complete string: -

```
oneLine.matches(".*kind.*");
```

Answer (score 4):

The [**`.matches`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method is intended to match the *entire* string.  So you need something like:

```
.*kind.*
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Gb5MQZ

Answer (score 2):

Matches tries to match the whole string (implicit `^` and `$` anchors), you want to use `contains()` to check for parts of the string.