# Java 1.7 String class matches method returns false when it should be true

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String s = "Remediation Release 16  - Test Status Report_04032014.xlsx";

s.matches("([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(xlsx))$)"); // returns false
```

I've tried the exmaple on http://regex101.com/ and its says the match is true.

Is there some nuance of the matches method I am missing

Comment: possible duplicate of [string.matches(regex) returns false, although I think it should be true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613621/string-matchesregex-returns-false-although-i-think-it-should-be-true)

Comment: please note the rendering in the post of \ is actually \\ in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java `matches()` does perform the matching over the whole string. So you have to use `.*` at the begging of your regex.

```
s.matches(".*([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(xlsx))$)");
           ^^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the whole text in between the start and file extension.

Try with:

```
String s = "Remediation Release 16  - Test Status Report_04032014.xlsx";
//                                    | "Remediation" ... to ... "Report_04032014"
//                                    | is matched by ".+"
System.out.println(s.matches("([^\\s]+.+(\\.(?i)(xlsx))$)"));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

As `matches` matches the whole text:

- `[^\\s]` will match the beginning of your input.
- `.+` will match the file name
- `(\\.(?i)(xlsx))$)` will match the dot + extension, case-insensitive, followed by end of input

To prove this:

```
//                           | removed outer group
//                           |      | added group 1 here for testing purposes
//                           |      |   | this is now group 2
//                           |      |   |               | removed outer group
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+(.+)(\\.(?i)(xlsx))$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Group 1: " + m.group(1) + " | group 2: " + m.group(2));
}
```

**Output**

```
Group 1:  Release 16  - Test Status Report_04032014 | group 2: .xlsx
```

Also as demonstrated, you don't need the outer parenthesis in your initial `matches` argument.